# CSS Drop-Down Menu issues

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I'm making a wordpress theme and I have some problems with the menu codification. My menu has sub-menus but they are displaying in the wrong way, And I don't know what to do to make them look like a Drop-Down menu. [Here's the link to my site.](http://danithemes.fanscity.eu/marte)

Would you mind giving me a CSS code (only) for a really simple dropdown menu? In my website, the menu with sub-categories is 'TV Shows' and the Subcategories are 'Pretty Little Liars', 'Resurrection', and 'Chasing Life'. I need a CSS to make them drop-down from 'Tv Shows'.

This is my CSS Code for the links

```
#menu {
    height:55px;
background-color: #000;
    width:100%;
top:0px;
left:0px;
z-index:101;
text-align:center;
text-transform:uppercase;
position:relative;
}

.menulinks {
float:right;
}

#menucontainer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:900px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#menucontainer a {
color:#fff;
}

#menucontainer a:hover {
color:#fff;
}

#menucontainer ul { 
list-style: none;
padding:7px; 
color:#A4A4A4;
}

#menucontainer ul a {
color:#848484;
}

#menucontainer li a {
color:#848484;
}

#menucontainer li { 
display: inline; 
margin-right:3px;
margin-left:3px;
padding:3px;
color:#848484;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This. [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/kannor/m6prd5Lh/)

```css
ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #262222;
  color: #fff;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
ul li ul li { 
  background: #262222; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover { 
  background: #a1a1a1;
}
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
 <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Menu1</li>
    <li>Menu2
        <ul>
            <li>Sub Menu</li>
            <li>Another Sub Menu</li>
            <li>And Anthor Sub Menu</li>
        </ul>
   </li>
  <li>Menu3</li>
  <li>Menu4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is more than just CSS. You have to make sure the HTMl is built to accept both. You have to have a ul tag within a ul tag to cause the secondary drop down.

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/philhoyt/pen/ujHzd) link for exactly what your looking for I think:

```
    <h1>Simple Pure CSS Drop Down Menu</h1>
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
<ul>
  <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 1</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Good luck!

Comment: I'm not using directly HTML to display the menu links, I'm using the Wordpress Menu editor. Thank you so much for your answer, but what I need right now is a CSS Code for the menu to display as Drop-Down. Again, Thanks!!!

Comment: Check the link I added. The codepen has the CSS as well for you to look at.